# How to set AVPlayer controller in lock mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

How to set background iOS media AVPlayer like this

[image]

Left and right hand side players are needed.

Till now what I have

[image]

All the play, pause, previous, next are working.

I need to display songName, artistName, albumArt, seekBar.

Comment: chek my answer ..............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set information in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter like this.

```
 Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

    if (playingInfoCenter) {


        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"AlbumArt"]];


        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                         MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                         MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration,
                         MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate,
                         nil];

        NSError *playerError;

//        AVAudioPlayer*   audioPlayer4 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"This That (Dil Wali Gal) - Ammy Virk (DJJOhAL.Com)" ofType:@".mp3"]] error:&playerError];
//        
//        NSLog(@"%f",audioPlayer4.duration);

        NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"DIL vali gal",
                           @"ammy virk",
                           @"30",
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                           nil];
        NSDictionary *mediaInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];



        [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Title" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Author" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Album" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:mediaInfo];


    }
```

and import this frameworks

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h>
```

Comment: Where should I add this class

Comment: when you are playing the song. add all information in it.

Comment: you need to set value MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration seek bar work automatically

Comment: get your mp3 duration with my commented code. set the value MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration .

Comment: @AMIamitekh what happend